# Lucene.Net Search List

Tags: lucene.net, sitecore

I'm using Sitecore and have a multilist field I'd like to use Lucene to search on.  The problem I have is that the field is a pipe-delimited list of actual values and there could be between 0 and an infinite (theoretically speaking, actually there's probably only a thousand or two possibilities) number of items in this list.  I haven't been able to successfully use a wildcard query and I can't envision how to break this field up into multiple fields since there's an unknown number of items in the list.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the problem? Do you have a field that can multiple (many) values or is it more complex than that?

Comment: Sure, for example, the field I am trying to search on contains the value:

{303FF303-E8A7-456B-8861-4D7B9CE92D88}|{F88DF50F-928B-41AC-9280-3964AEFA530E}|{B0A7516B-1C97-4134-8E06-73433E3AE0B7}

And in my application I need to grab all documents that have the value {303FF303-E8A7-456B-8861-4D7B9CE92D88} in this field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used a similar technique in searches to search within a category heirarchy. I use the following method to build the query, leaving the hard work to the QueryParser class.  I usually add this query to a BooleanQuery.

The QueryParser usually does a great job, I often use it for building most of my Lucene queries - it seems to do a better job than me when building a specific query a lot of the time!!

Another thing you can do is to use the QueryParser to build it, then set a breakpoint and have a look at how the query has been created, then update your code with the specific query type.

```cs
private Query GetQuery(Sitecore.Data.ID id)
{
    string categoryId = id.Guid.ToString(); //turn ID to string
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(); //use standard analyzer
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("categories", analyzer); //search inside category field
    Query query = parser.Parse(categoryId); //get the query
    return query;
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach about using QueryParser for all my fields but the query turned out to be ridiculously slow when I tried to add two wild card queries to my boolean query using this query. 

Is this always the case that QueryParser is slow than handwriting queries?