# Lucene.net search on filed that is a list

Tags: lucene.net

tried [this approach][1] but did not work for me
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917405/lucene-net-search-list

I have a field that is a coma separated list of ids... like 500, 212, 303, ...etc.

When I'm indexing/search I'm using an PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper .. and for that field I already tried whitespace and standaranalyzer..

Also tried replacing the coma for a white space, separate numbers _ (leaving *500*, *212*, and also add it when searching) and adding a wildcard on the search.

Currently on search, while building the query I tried the linked solution and used

```
private Query GetPopIDQuery(string popID)
        {            
            StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48); //use standard analyzer
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "popfield", analyzer); //search inside category field
            Query query = parser.Parse(popID); //get the query
            return query;
        }
```

So no luck yet... when I search for an ID that should be on tthat list... I get empty results.... is there a best aproach on handling index/search of a filed that has a list of numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: On database (yes, its old database migrated, shouldt be structured like that). there is a field pop, that has values like 20, 45, 400, 450, 12 .... I tried indexing it as it is, replacing "," by space, replacing by _20_, _45_, but still not sure how to solve it

Comment: I suspect a better approach would be to [add multiple values to the same field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028490). This would allow you to eliminate the string splitting on each document during search.

Comment: Excelent! I did not know the multiple values approach! Thanks for the tip!